# Mysql PHP won't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which ill show some information from the database  but it won't work 
Connecta.php code

```
<?php
                $dbhost = '*';
                $dbuser = '*';
                $dbpass = 'nQ4*jH5!';
                $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
                if(! $conn )
                {
                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                mysql_select_db('*');
                mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

?>
```

And this is the source of he page that i have problem with

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; 
require("../connecta.php");
$sql = 'SELECT mirror_link
        FROM fallaga_tbl WHERE id=\'$id\' ';
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

 ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Zone-P || Fallaga Mirror</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../home.css">
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.fallega.tn/icon.gif" height="350" width="350">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
        <div class="header">
            <div align="center"><a class="titlee" >Fallaga Mirror</a><br><img  width="500px" src="http://tunisiaface.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/l.png"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="../index.php">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="../News.php">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="../NOTIFY/NOTIFY.php">NOTIFY</a></li>
                <li><a href="../NOTIFY/MassNotify.php">MASS NOTIFY</a></li>
                <li><a href="../ONHOLD.php">ONHOLD</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Archive.php">ARCHIVE</a></li>
                <li><a href="../About.php">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
        <iframe src="
         <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { echo "{$row['mirror_link']}"; } mysql_close($conn) ; ?>  
        " style="width:770px;height:500px;">
          <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
        </div>

         <div class="bottom">
        Zone-p - Fallaga mirror service &copy; 2014 - <a style="color:white;" href="https://www.facebook.com/mahdi.com.tn ">by Màh Di</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When i open the page from my browser i see the html and no error but for iframe nothing came in src="" it still empty
Can show me what's wrong ?

Comment: What does the page look like if you "View Source". Looks like you have a while loop in your IFRAME SRC which could potentially put multiple URL's there. ALSO - I would suggest you move away from using the `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated.

Comment: @ajtrichards_wales when in view source i see     <iframe src="
       
    " style="width:770px;height:500px;"> like this !

Comment: @user3192198 post inside code of connecta.php also

Comment: Try typing `echo $sql;` and see what's returned and then run the query in the MySQL command line

Comment: @DeepakGoswami done i add the connecta page source

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems you should use " instead of ' on line 3, otherwise the \'$id\' in SQL only be known as a string value '$id', not a valid id value by MYSQL.

Your code on line 3:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT mirror_link
        FROM fallaga_tbl WHERE id=\'$id\' ';
```

It should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT mirror_link
        FROM fallaga_tbl WHERE id='{$id}'";
```

Besides You can also change your code line 1 to

```
$id = mysql_escape_string( $_REQUEST['id'] );
```

to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: @user3192198 Given that `$id` comes from the request you must not take this code literally, because it lacks proper SQL escaping.

Comment: @tanaydin And you should be critical of answers that clearly don't care about sql injection attack vectors.